# Web.sitemap open pdf in new page

Tags: asp.net

This is my code

```
<siteMapNode url="/guide_saisie.pdf" title="?" description="GuideSaisie" target="_blank" />
```

No page open and I get this error: HTTP verb POST not allowed to acces to the
'/.../guide_saisie.pdf' is not authorized.

But if I put the url direct in my browser its work.

How to open the pdf in new page whit sitemap?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java script window.open(url) work well in my case....

Answer (score 1):

Have you try to use a relative url?

```
<siteMapNode url="~/guide_saisie.pdf" title="?" description="GuideSaisie" target="_blank" />
```